# ESRI Search Widget - Alter Search Parameters (ArcGIS JS v4.9)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

The Search widget within the ArcGIS JavaScript API (v 4.9) works by returning all records that contain your search string.  In other words, if you search for "123" You'll get "**123** S Main St", "5**123** W Oak St", "Painting **123**", and more.  I just want to limit the search to only those records *starting* with the search string, not everything containing it.  There seems to be no exposed way however to alter what appears to be the "LIKE %search string%" query baked into the widget.  Has anyone been able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The default source for the Search widget is the [Esri World Geocoder](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/overview-world-geocoding-service.htm). The [suggest endpoint](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocoding-suggest.htm) of the Geocoder does not allow this query format that you're asking about, so I don't think that's possible. If you have a Feature Service of your address points, you can do what you want by defining your own ["source"](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Search.html#sources) to point the Search widget at your Feature Service, and then using [`esriConfig.request.interceptors`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-config.html#request) to modify the request -- something like this:

```
esriConfig.request.interceptors.push({
  // set the `urls` property to the URL of the FeatureLayer so that this
  // interceptor only applies to requests made to the FeatureLayer URL
  urls: "https://ccmap.cccounty.us/arcgis/rest/services/LUCA/LUCA_ADDRESS/FeatureServer/0",
  // use the BeforeInterceptorCallback to check if the query of the
  // FeatureLayer has a where property set.
  // if so, then modify the "where" property how we want it to be.
  before: function(params) {
    if (params.requestOptions.query.where) {
      params.requestOptions.query.where = params.requestOptions.query.where.replace(
        "'%",
        "'"
      );
    }
  }
});
```

Full demo [here](https://codepen.io/gavinr/pen/bQOKJW?editors=0010).

Comment: one problem: if a layer url ends with ...FeatureServer/1 another service ending on /FeatureServer/11 or FeatureServer/10 will also be intercepted.